# How to create drag and drop and forward to some function in django?

Tags: django, drag-and-drop

I have a django website, and I would like to implement drag&drop to my form. This part is looking very old compare to the rest of site. Problem is that I don't know javascript, I have tried to make if from tutorials but did not make any sense. Can you help me to get simple solution for this. Any ideas how to do this with zero knowledge of js?

cal.py

```
def OnlyCAL(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DocumentForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            output = io.BytesIO()
            newdoc = request.FILES['docfile']
                #pandas calculations

            response = HttpResponse(
                output, content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
            response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=%s' % filename
            return response
    else:
        form = DocumentForm()
    return render(request, 'cal.html', { 'form': form, 'page_title':page_title })
```

forms.py

```
class DocumentForm(forms.Form):
    docfile = forms.FileField(label='Select a file')
```

cal.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
      <form action="{% url "cal" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="dropzone">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ message }}
      <p>{{ form.non_field_errors }}</p>
      <p>{{ form.docfile.label_tag }} {{ form.docfile.help_text }}</p>
      <p>
            {{ form.docfile.errors }}
            {{ form.docfile }}
      </p>
      <p><input type="submit" value="Upload and Download!"/></p>
      </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),
    path('cal/', cal.OnlyCAL, name='cal'),
]
```

Like this:

[image]

Comment: I used jquery drag and drop. here is a guide [link](https://www.elated.com/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/) .

Comment: google django and dropzone.js lots of good tutorials on it

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this for one of my projects.

Take for example an **Exam**. Students were required to upload their exam file via a drop box system. As I do not know your models per say, Hopefully you can re-apply the method to your own project.

Firstly, the backend:

***Backend***

The form was simple. a form with just the file field.

**forms.py**

```py
class ExamFileForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model= Exam
        fields= ('file',)
```

The view. simple FBV which extracts the header from the AJAX call to pull through the id of the exam. I then search for the `Exam` instance, validate the form and save the file to the instance, then return a positive JSON response back to the AJAX call. **Else** I return a failed response.

**views.py**

```py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def load_exam_file(request):
    exam_id = dict(request.headers.copy()).pop('exam_id', None)
    exam= Exam.objects.get(id=exam_id)
    form  = ExamFileForm(data=request.POST, files=request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        exam.file = form.cleaned_data['file']
        exam.save()
        return JsonResponse({
            'uploaded':True, 
        })
    return JsonResponse({'uploaded':False})
```

***Template***

The html is similar to your a simple drag box design to allow users to drop element inside.

**HTML:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="box" method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}           
    <div class="box__dragbox">
        <div class="box__dragbox_background"></div>
        <p class="box__dragtext jlrFontMediumBold">Drag files to upload here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="box__uploading">Uploading…</div>
    <div class="box__success">Done!</div>
    <div class="box__error">Error! <span></span>.</div>
</form>
```

The JQuery, a variety of different event handlers to change the behaviour of the box as I drag over and away from the box. The main event is the `drop` in which, when you drop the file an AJAX call is created and sent back to the backend for evaluation (This also brings the form data and id is registered in the `header`.

> *Note: Ensure you pass the id into the template. For example I passed `exam_id` into the args of the view, then called {{ exam_id }} in the header*

**JQuery:**

```js
$(document).on("dragover", 'html', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
});

$(document).on("drop", 'html', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); 
});

// Drag enter
$(document).on('dragenter','.box__dragbox', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".box__dragtext").text("Drop here!");
    $(".box__dragbox_background").css({'opacity':'1'})
});

// Drag over
$(document).on('dragover','.box__dragbox', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".box__dragtext").text("Drop here!");
    $(".box__dragbox_background").css({'opacity':'1'})
});

$(document).on('dragleave','.box__dragbox', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".box__dragtext").text("Drag files to upload here");
    $(".box__dragbox_background").css('opacity','0')
});

// Drop
$(document).on('drop','.box__dragbox', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".box__dragtext").text("Uploaded!");

    var file = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files;
    var fd = new FormData();
    fd.append('file', file[0])
    uploadData(fd);
});

function uploadData(formdata){

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': $.cookie('csrftoken'),'id':{{ exam_id }},
        url: window.location.href,
        data: formdata, 
        success: function(response){
        if (response.uploaded) {
            console.log("Uploaded!");
        }
        else {
            console.log("Did not upload :(")
        }
        },
        async: false,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
    });
    }
```

The CSS is just a design I put together for a simple dropbox.

**CSS:**

```
.box__dragndrop,
.box__uploading,
.box__success,
.box__error {
  display: none;
}

.box__dragbox_background {
    background-color:#ebebeb;
    opacity:0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transition:'opacity 0.5s ease-in-out'
}

.box__dragbox {
    border: 3px dashed #c1c1c1;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
}

.box__dragtext {
    color: grey;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: @Levis Can you tell me how to change my `views (cal.py)` to JsonResponse? It returns to me my same document without pandas calculations, it means I didn't do anything right.